# How to get popups to be defined outside the page they're used in?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

According to this github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4565

this issue is reportedly resolved yet I have tried to place a popup outside the div of the page a popup button is using latest jqm 1.4.5 and was unable to get the popup to work unless its popup is within the same div as the page it is on.
In short this example code below has to be defined on the current page for the popup to work (just as the initial dilemma the github above is presenting).

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup">
```

The goal is to put all data-role popups on one html page (the index.html is what i'm guessing could work) and be able to just reference that popup through only the use of a button on another page.

This would result in a cleaner and more efficient method when dealing with reusing a multitude of popups within an application. Unless I'm doing something wrong I thought this issue was addressed in the github in which case it should work.

Anyone know if this is possible or fixed or has an idea on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a popup outside the page div within JQM you must instantiate the popup on DOM ready and enhance its contents.

To do this you should have the following function:

```
$(function(){
   $(".class_myPopup").enhanceWithin().popup();
});
```

that is run when you load your site... I have it in my bespoke JS script that is included in my header.

Comment: I added that function already but it only allows me to use the popup without having to put the same jquery script on each page a popup is on which is a step closer to what i want. I still however have to put a popup on every page to get it to work rather than reference it from an external page like what can be done with the jquery script.

Comment: I failed to mention the popup will just show up on every page but before its reference button is ever clicked whether ajax-data=false or true...I need it so the popup isn't automatically executed and only to run when a user clicks its reference button on a corresponding page. This is when the popup is in index.html btw...

Comment: okay, so i've been experimenting with more things and found this to be working as a Multi-HTML template. When all is in one single html file. Do you know if this also works for Multi-Page templates where i can put the code in index.html for it to be referenced to external pages? Thanks for the prior feedback as well.

Comment: Hi - I use multi page templates... ie. I have my popups in popups.php and I include this in whichever script I want to use the popups in, placing the include code OUTSIDE the <page></page> div tags. This way I can use the same popups on multiple pages, without re-writing the code.  If you are using AJAX you should be able to just include the file on your first page, and be able to use it everywhere.

Comment: finally got it working now...ur answer was indeed correct but i wasn't utilizing it right...i had to use $(function () {
    $("[data-role=popup]").popup().enhanceWithin();
}); on the index.html to finally get it working...thanks a bunch for all the help!...If i could upvote ur answer right now I would but my rep is too low

Comment: glad its all working :) took me a while to figure it out too!!